# Получить таблицу символов юникода вида код=описание на русском

Tags: unicode

Нужно сформировать таблицу символов из кода символа и его описания, к примеру, U+1F63C=Кот с кривой улыбкой.
в их Репозитории на github, описание ко многим символам, в частности выше приведенному, найти не могу.

Comment: http://unicode-table.com/ru

Comment: в их Репозитории на github, описание ко многим символам, в частности выше приведенному, найти не могу. А инструмент генерации таблиц  не генерирует описания.